# .Net Framework / Standard Access Registry

Tags: .net, registry, .net-standard

I have the following scenario where registry access is not working with a .Net Standard 2.0 dll.  There are two parts to the program shown below...

1. A Shared library that is .Net Standard 2.0.  It references the Microsoft.Win32.Registry nuget package (v4.4).  The shared library has the following method in it:

   ```
   public static void GetRegistryValue()
   {
       // it does successfully enter this if statment
       if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
       {
           var y = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine;  // this returns null
           var x = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default); // this throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Registry is not supported on this platform.'
       }
   }
   ```
2. A main application that is full .Net Framework.  I have tried .4.6.1 and .4.7.1.  The main application references the shared library.  When the main application calls GetRegistryValue(), it does not work.

Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine returns null, so that will not work.

RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default) throws a System.PlatformNotSupportedException.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's by design. Don't add such Windows only dependencies to a .NET Standard class library. At compile time, it would simply mislead MSBuild/NuGet to choose a wrong assembly (which returns the `null` or throws `PlatformNotSupportedException` you see).

Such references must be only present in your .NET Framework projects, and about how to move the references and related code base to the upper layer, you have to do you own consideration and refactoring. Too broad for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem. In our situation the netstandard2.0 library has many methods that do not need the registry access and a handful that do. The library maintainer expects consumers to only call those methods if they are running on Windows.

I discovered that if I reference the netstandard2.0 artifacts from the Microsoft.Win32.Registry package in my .NET Framework 4.6.1 application the third party code gets null values for LocalMachine (and crashes). However, if I reference the 4.6.1 framework artifacts from the Nuget package the third party library reads the registry successfully.